# Several foreign keys in same table EF Core 7

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-code-first-mapping

I have two entities `CodeMaster` and `Employee`. In `Employee`, I have more foreign key optional properties to navigate to the `CodeMaster` entity. When I insert data into `Employee`, I get this error:

> Inner Exception 1:
> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employees_CodeMasters_BloodGroupId". The conflict occurred in database "AproPayrollDB", table "dbo.CodeMasters", column 'Id'

Here is my `CodeMaster` class:

```
public class CodeMaster : AuditableEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CodeTypeId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public virtual CodeType CodeType { get; set; }   
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee

```
public class Employee : AuditableEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeFullName { get; set; }
    public string WorkName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string MotherName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; } = null!;
    public long? EmpTypeId { get; set; }

    public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public long? DesignationId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public long? BloodGroupId { get; set; }

    public string AprosoftEmailId { get; set; }
    public string PersonalEmailId { get; set; }
    public string AprosoftSkypeId { get; set; }

    public string MsteamsId { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyContactPerson { get; set; }
    public long? RelationshipId { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyNumber { get; set; }
    public long? LocationOfRemoteWorkStatus { get; set; }
    public long? UpazilaId { get; set; }
    public long? DistrictId { get; set; }
    public long? DivisionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RetirementDate { get; set; }

    public long? EmpStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId))]
    public virtual CodeMaster Department { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BloodGroupId))]
    public virtual CodeMaster BloodGroup { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DistrictId))]
    public virtual CodeMaster District { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
builder.Entity<Employee>()
              .HasOne(e => e.Department)
              .WithMany()
              .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId);

builder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasOne(e => e.District)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DistrictId);

builder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasOne(e => e.BloodGroup)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BloodGroupId);
```

I want to create relations between `CodeMaster` and `Employee` entities using `DepartmentId`, `DistrictId`, `BloodGroupId` and so on.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You are inserting a record with an id that does not exist in the related table.  Insert that record first and then it will work fine.

Comment: A FK or composite FK in one table must link to the PK in another. If Employees are associated to a CodeMaster, then either Employee needs a CodeMasterId, or if they can be associated to many CodeMasters, a many-to-many joining table of EmployeeId+CodeMasterId.

Comment: Not sure if related to the concrete issue, but this property `public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` in `CodeMaster` looks unpaired, which means EFC considers 4th hidden relationship in addition to the 3 explicitly defined by the fluent API, which in general will cause you problems.

Comment: I used optional foreign key

Comment: When foreign key is optional that time passes null or valid value then its works fine. I tried to foreign key value 0 that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Db first or code first?

Comment: code first approach

Comment: "nullable reference types" is enable?

Comment: Yes, allow nullable.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Relationship navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#reference-navigations) :

> When using C# nullable reference types, reference navigations must be nullable for optional relationships...

In the OP's code :

```cs
public class Employee : AuditableEntity
{
    public long? BloodGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BloodGroupId))]
    public virtual CodeMaster BloodGroup { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The foreign key property `long? BloodGroupId` is nullable, but the corresponding navigation property `CodeMaster BloodGroup` isn't. I don't know how EF Core interprete this inconsistency, but fix it can resolve the problem :

```cs
public class Employee : AuditableEntity
{
    public long? BloodGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BloodGroupId))]
    public virtual CodeMaster? BloodGroup { get; set; }

    ...
}
```